# How to acquire expat.h for the compilation of git?

Tags: git, compilation, dependencies, build-dependencies, slackware

I need install `git` (v 2.0) on slackware 14. I experience an error during

```
$ make install prefix=/usr/local
```

run in the source root:

```
LINK git-http-fetch
CC http-push.o
  http-push.c:17:19: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory
  #include <expat.h>
                  ^
  compilation terminated.
  make: *** [http-push.o] Error 1
```

What is missing for the compilation to proceed?

Answer (score 12):

I also faced same problem today.
My environment is Scientific Linux (`2.6.32-431.17.1el6.x86_64`).

Though I already have package:
expat.x86_64

the following package was also necessary to do "make":
expat-devel.x86_64

Therefore, I did

```
# yum install expat-devel
```

Though the environment is different, I hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the [libexpat1-dev library](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libexpat1-dev) (Xml parsing c library)

If you can install it first (maybe with [`slapt-get`](http://www.slackwiki.com/Slapt-get)), then you can go on with the compilation of git.